# Kill like vim or Sublime Text

Tags: deletion

I'm "new" with Emacs. I'm making my own set up but I can't do one thing with killing words. You know what `M-DEL` does by default, but I want to make like Sublime Text or VIM. I'll do an example (this is the original text):

`Hi, I'm captainepoch
< first post here!`

And this is how I do on `vim` or `Sublime Text`:

```
Hi, I'm captainepoch
< first post here▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi, I'm captainepoch
< first post▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi, I'm captainepoch
< first▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi, I'm captainepoch
<▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi, I'm captainepoch
▮
```

*Here, there's nothing at the beginning of the line and doing `M-DEL` in vim makes the cursor go to the end of the previous line.*

```
Hi, I'm captainepoch▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi, I'm▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi, I'▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi, I▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi,▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi▮
```

*This final `M-DEL` will end up deleting the whole text.*

```
▮
```

A friend of mine did this function:

```el
(defun backward-kill-word (arg)
  (interactive "p")
  (let ((init-pos (point))
        (line-begin (line-beginning-position)))
    (if (/= (point) line-begin)
        (kill-word (- arg)))))
```

And it does the job until it got the `<`, which does this:

```
Hi, I'm captainepoch
<▮
```

*Do `M-DEL`*

```
Hi, I'm▮
```

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you please clarify exactly what you want your function to do?  It's a little hard to follow what you want from the example.

Comment: Hi @Dan, thank you! I want to delete words individually, in the example it does from bottom to top. When I use emacs and do M-DEL, It deletes words but if the last 2 characters are `< ` (< and a space), it deletes that two and the previous word on the previous line. I'd like to delete text as Sublime does.

Comment: @captainepoch I have updated the question.. I hope that's what you meant.

Comment: @captainepoch [`syntax-subword`](https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/syntax-subword) package might get you close to what you want; I have not used it.

Comment: @KaushalModi Thank you so much, It's just what I mean! And the package works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came from sublime as well and was looking for the behavior. I achieve the results you are describing by using `syntax-subword` which I think can be installed through MELPA. Here is my `syntax-subword` configuration (I use `use-package`):

```
(use-package syntax-subword
  :init
  (setq syntax-subword-skip-spaces t)
  :config
  (global-syntax-subword-mode))
```

For you, it should be enough to do `M-x package-install syntax-subword`, and then add the following to your config file:

```
(setq syntax-subword-skip-spaces t)
(global-syntax-subword-mode))
```

I hope this setup works for you; it has been so long since I have configured Emacs without `use-package` that I might have missed a step (e.g., you may need to `require` the package). However, on my setup using that package I tested your example, and it works the way you want it to.

Comment: You solution is just what I want, thank you so much!